# VbScript to accept Inputs for a domain name

Tags: vbscript, hta, adsi

I have below vb script, which is working,I wanted to allow users to choose any of the below three domains.

I have three domains

```
ab.ac.xyd
lud.local
dul.net
```

so if i Write for ab.ac.xyd it would be like below as a static In my script, which i wanted to make user optional to choose... However i wanted to allow user to choose from above three domains out of only one should be selected.. is it possible with vbscript or HTA... ? whatever is easy one can i have a sample code...

```
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2 
Set objGroup = GetObject _
   ("LDAP://CN=Y_MOM_Server1,OU=M1 OD,DC=ab,DC=ac,DC=xyz") 
objGroup.Put "adminDescription", "test1:test2:test3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally.. thought to use three scripts... :( .. if you have something in mind to accept this you can list here anytime...
Thank you
ED